# How to add text under the button previously placed as leftCalloutAccessoryView of MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I want to basically do this: [ETA info under the button with a car image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unFs6.png)

How can I add text just at the bottom of the button? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution a long time ago but forgot to mention it here.

Here it is:

Just create a `Vertical StackView`, set its alignment as `Center` and distribution as `Fill`, and put your `label` and `image` in it. Make your `label` hidden at first. Assign the `StackView` as the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`. When you got the ETA info, just make the `label` unhidden **inside** an animation code.

That's it! It will behave just like in the Apple's Map app.